# using set and expect in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, set, expect

I am trying to ssh into few systems (read from test.txt file) using expect within a shell script and execute commands on each.  The script returns an error "invalid command name". Am I using set and expect in an incorrect way here?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set username "root"
set pass "mypassword"
set fd [open /home/test.txt r]
set host [read $fd]
foreach line $host {
   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n root@$host 'ls; pwd'
        expect "User:" { send "${username}\r" }
        expect "root's Password:" { send "${pass}\r" }
        expect eof
}
```

Error returned

```
./expect.sh
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n root@10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2

 'ls
invalid command name "pwd'"
    while executing
"pwd' "
    ("foreach" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"foreach line $host {
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with double quotes and error does not occur anymore.. However the script still prompts for a password.. The output returned is as below.                                                   -- spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n root@10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
 ls; pwd
Warning: Permanently added '10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, expect parsed `;` as a command separator, and couldn't handle `pwd'`.

That's because there are no single-quoted strings in the language.

Expect is tcl, you have to use double quotes: `"ls; pwd"`

Comment: +1. To emphasize, single quotes have no meaning in Tcl. The equivalent to shell's single quotes is braces: `{ls; pwd}`